# Android: Out of memory Error on launch of Drawer layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory, navigation-drawer

I am facing out of memory error when i debugged my code it is failing in below line of code:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
```

The error is as below:

```
01-01 23:16:14.611  24083-24083/? E/CrashReporting﹕ ParseCrashReporting caught a OutOfMemoryError exception for wishlist.oj.app. Building report.
01-01 23:16:14.613  24083-24083/? E/CrashReporting﹕ Handling exception for crash
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 86400012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 66MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2578)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2471)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at wishlist.oj.app.home.ActivityDrawer.onCreate(ActivityDrawer.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
```

My activity_drawer XML code looks like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".ActivityDrawer">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            theme="@style/MyToolbarThemeSimple.Base"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--  The Navigation drawer      -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/cardview_drawer"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have tried many things like I increased the heap size to -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m by using Compiler VM options.
Also, I checked the option "compile independent modules in parallel" present inside Settings => Build,Execution,Development Enviroment => compiler
But nothing worked out .. Any help??

Comment: are you getting the same thing on a device?

Comment: It looks like you have an ImageView somewhere with a drawable/picture that is way too large.

Comment: @Virus - yes ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link showing how to load bitmaps efficiently with sample code.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

This type of error usually occurs if your image is too large to be loaded (causing an `OutOfMemoryError`.

I would suggest scaling down your image, or using a lower resolution image, so it can be loaded into the memory easier.

There are also a variety of sources you can visit including the [Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) with a sample app, as well as YouTube videos such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8).